# Unable to view Documents or Downloads folder remotely

Tags: catalina, permission, file-sharing

I used to be able to access folders on my remote systems without problem.

Now in Catalina when I find my computers on my LAN and try to connect to them, I can only see the contents of ~/ and that of any folder I made.  The default folders (such as `Documents`, `Downloads` appear empty, something I've confirmed my navigating to it in the terminal.

I *assume* this is another idiotic protect-the-user-from-themself-at-all-cost-even-if-it-messes-with-normal-users move in Catalina, but how can I actually access the folder?  I'm logged in as myself, so there should be no permissions issue (all other folders/files have the same permissions anyways).  On the remote end, by screensharing at the exact same time I can confirm that there are files present in the folders.  No dialog is presented asking for access like many apps do now to access such files.

I even added my home folder as a separate shared folder, and granted full access to everyone.  But to no avail.

Any ideas on how to enable access?

Comment: You have to give Terminal access to both of those folders.  It would be under  Security and Privacy in System Preferences in the Accessibility “tab”.  And yes, this is Apple protecting you from yourself. We need sn “expert mode” that turns all of this off.

Comment: Allan: that does not work.  I have given Terminal on both computers access to Files and Folders and Full Disk Access, and restarted it but I can't access it

Comment: Problem is, I can’t replicate.  I’m on an iPad connecting via SSH and I can’t get it to behave like yours.  Just out of curiosity, can you `cd` into the directory?  (i.e. ` cd ~/Documents`)

Comment: Also, if you’re local, can you see the directory in Terminal?

Comment: Allan: I just mounted the drive in Finder (equiv to `mount afp://network/username/ /Volumes/username`).  When I view the remote home folder in Finder or `ls` it in Terminal, I can see the Documents/Desktop folders, and I can double click to open (in Finder) or `cd` to them without error, just also without any files.  When I go to that machine, files are visible from Terminal and Finder without problem

Comment: So locally it works as expected, remote it doesn’t.  Are you using ZSH or Bash?  If so, can we get a look at your config files?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today on a machine with Ventura.

While file sharing, accounts and everything seemed to be configured correctly, I could not see the contents of the remote `Desktop` , `Documents` and `Downloads` folders. I could see and write to the other folders, like Music or the root of the share which is my `$HOME`.

The problem disappeared after completely disabling "File Sharing" in General > Sharing, rebooting, and re-enabling  "File Sharing".

Also check under "Privacy & Security" > "Full Disk Access" if you have "smbd" allowed.